# Thread interrupt status getting cleared - possible Java bug

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, interrupt

This is with reference to [Path#register](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#register%28java.nio.file.WatchService,%20java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind...%29) method. If a thread is running a block containing the method and another thread interrupts it beforehand. Then it is found that the method clears the interrupt status.

No where in the document is it mentioned that it clears the interrupt status of the thread.

To replicate

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

import static java.nio.file.LinkOption.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;

import java.nio.file.attribute.*;

public class WatchDir {

    private final WatchService watcher;
    
    private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
        // interrupt itself
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        boolean before = Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();
        WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
        boolean after = Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();

        if (before) {
            if (!after) {
                System.out.println("--------------------BUG-------------------");
                System.out.format("Interrupt Status: true before making call to Path#register for folder folder: %s\n", dir);
                System.out.format("Interrupt Status: false after making call to Path#register for folder folder: %s\n", dir);
                System.out.println("The interrupt status was cleared by `register` (Unexpected Behavior).");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a bug on your machine. The interrupt was not cleared after call to Path#register. Works as expected");
                System.out.println("Works well on your machine. Didn't work for me on Windows and Ubuntu with Java 7");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
     */
    WatchDir(Path dir) throws IOException {
        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        register(dir);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // register directory and process its events
        Path dir = Paths.get(".");
        new WatchDir(dir);
    }
}
```

Above you can observe that interrupt status is cleared after calling `register` function. Sample output:

```
--------------------BUG-------------------
Interrupt Status: true before making call to Path#register for folder folder: .
Interrupt Status: false after making call to Path#register for folder folder: .
The interrupt status was cleared by `register` (Unexpected Behavior).
```

This issue arose because a service was found to be still active even after requested for shutdown. Any ideas?

edit: It turns out it is happening only in Windows and Linux. Mac behaves as expected. My OS: Win 7 64-bit. JDK 1.7.0_11.
Also found on: Ubuntu 14.04 Java 1.7.0_45-b18

Comment: [This could be the cuplrit](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/fs/AbstractPoller.java#AbstractPoller.Request.awaitResult%28%29) - it gets called at some stage by the [register method specific to Windows Paths](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPath.java).

Comment: You should make that comment an answer @assylias.

Comment: @Gray I did not look in details so not 100% sure this is it (but it would make sense).

Comment: @assylias or Jatin, are you going to file a bug report?

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff I have not.

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff I already have. But it is still not listed. For reference: Bug Review ID- 2436477

Answer (score -1):

The problem maybe lies in the `catch` block:

```
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(WatchDir.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Try adding

```
// Restore the interrupted status
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

in the `catch` block.

More on this topic can be found in the post ["Java theory and practice: Dealing with InterruptedException"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html)

Comment: Thread containing that line is interrupting another thread rather than getting interrupted itself. Hence catch block is never called. Basically it is the caller thread.

Comment: Then my suggestion is to drill down in method calls and check where an `InterruptedException` has been handled without setting the interrupted flag properly.

Comment: Exactly, that is the question. My code does not have any of the InterruptedException. Documentation in any of the used methods doesnot describe it

Comment: It would be nice if there's a chance to get the source code and `grep` for `InterruptedException`. If it failed then a decompilation may help :)

Comment: @BorisPavlović The code does swallow (ignore) an InterruptedException - see the link I posted in the comments above.

Comment: @assylias I don't know what's the license, but if the code can be modified there's a solution.

Comment: It turns out it is happening only in Windows. Mac behaves as expected. My OS: Win 7 64-bit. JDK 1.7.0_11 @assylias

Comment: @Jatin that makes sense. The class is os specific.

Comment: @assylias I have registered it as a bug. But I wonder they will look upon it as it is a trivial issue.

Answer (score -1):

The `interrupted` flag of a `Thread` is not a good field to rely on alone. You should monitor both the `interrupted` flag and watch for interrupts.

See [The Law of the Sabotaged Doorbell](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue146.html) for an excellent discussion.

An especially pertinent quote comes from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) (my emphasis):

> **interrupt** ... If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods of this class, then **its interrupt status will be cleared** and it will receive an InterruptedException.

Comment: Thanks :). I have solved the problem with a small other trick. But strictly for the question sake- It clears but doesn;t throw InterruptedException. That is the whole issue

Comment: @Jatin: you should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score -3):

It is simple as such .. Once you refered to interuption status internaly in the same thread. I t will be cleared.

If the interuption status is refered from another thread, it will not be cleared

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Thread.html The doc for calling `isInterrupted` method says: The interrupted status of the thread is unaffected by this method. So no

Comment: If you check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html
In the section The Interrupt Status Flag, they mention

The interrupt mechanism is implemented using an internal flag known as the interrupt status. Invoking Thread.interrupt sets this flag. "When a thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method Thread.interrupted, interrupt status is cleared. The non-static isInterrupted method, which is used by one thread to query the interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status flag."

Comment: Looks like you misread the code :). I have used `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and not `interrupted()`.